# Ĉu "gusti bone" tradukas al "to taste well" aŭ "to taste good"?

Tags: translation

Saluton. Duolingo tradukas la frazon "Ŝia kafo gustas bone." al "Her coffee tastes good."
Kial oni ne tradukas tion al "Her coffee tastes well."?
(Mi memorigas vin, ke la Esperantlingva frazo estas: Ŝia kafo gustas "bone.")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English the food is not actually doing the tasting, in that sentence the meaning of "taste" is "to have a specific flavor", so you go on telling what that flavor is, not how the flavour is "made available" to your mouth. For food, you'll see that English uses adjectives: it tastes good/bad/sour...

In Esperanto the mean of "gusti" is a bit different, the food actually creates the sensation (Kaŭzi agrablan aŭ malagrablan sensaĵon sur la lango k palato). So, you describe that action, the verb, and you use and adverb: *bone/malbone/acide*.

By the way, instead of *tio gustas bone* I usually hear:

```
Tio bongustas.
```

So, it is ok:

```
Tio gustas bone --> That tastes good
```

Comment: Dankegon pro via klarigo, Sinjoro Trápani.

Comment: Tasting is one of the things that is perceived differently between speakers of different languages. I like to add, just for a comparison, how Finnish with its grammatical cases expresses that. For tasting there are two possibilites.

• _Kahvi maistuu hyvä**ltä**_ : western dialect way with the [ablative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_case) indicating a metamophical movement towards the taster
• _Kahvi maistuu hyvä**lle**_ : eastern dialect way with the [allative case](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alativo) indicating a metamophical movement towards the goodness of the coffee